# django rest framework change primary key to use a unqiue field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model which is called `GameProfile`, which is a one to one relation with `User` model. I used `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` across all my design.

For the `GameProfile`, the user field is suppose to be the primary key for querying, it is unique but I did not set it up as a primary key. Is there a way to change the default behavior of django serializer to point to `user__id` as the primary key and always use it for retreiving the profile in the detail view?

```
class GameProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    """ 
    """
    user_pk = serializers.Field(source='user.id')

    class Meta:
        model = GameProfile


class GameProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    """
    queryset = GameProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GameProfileSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """ get_queryset
        """
        queryset = super(GameProfileViewSet, self).get_queryset()
        if not queryset.exists():
            raise Http404
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated() and not self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return queryset
```

please advise, thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assuming your `GameProfile` model looks like:

```
class GameProfile(models.Model)
    user = models.OneToOneField('User')
```

The serializer will be:

```
class GameProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user_id = serializers.Field(source='user.id')

    class Meta:
        model = GameProfile
```

Set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly:

```
    lookup_field = 'user_id'
```

Url will be:

```
/gameprofile/<user_id>
```

Comment: How would you do this except if you needed 2 fields to guarantee a unique lookup result? (ex. user_region and user_id, b/c user IDs are only unique per region?)

Comment: `lookup_field` should actually go on the View/ViewSet and not the serializer

Answer (score 17):

In order to get the URLs to work, you might need to add `lookup_field` on the ViewSet, not just on the serializer.  So you would have:

```
class GameProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = GameProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GameProfileSerializer
    lookup_field = 'user__id'
```

In this case the `lookup_field` uses the double-underscore notation rather than the dot notation (dots won't work in the regular expressions in the URL patterns).  I was unable to get the solution proposed by [@almalki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2074398/almalki) and [@patsweet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1309020/patsweet) to work; according to the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#how-hyperlinked-views-are-determined) on serializers, "The value of this option [`lookup_field`] should correspond both with a kwarg in the URL conf, and with a field on the model", so it's possible that it doesn't work with RelatedFields.

Comment: thanks worked adding lookup_field to modelviewset is enough

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want a url structure like so:

```
/api/<GameProfile-resource>/<user-pk>
```

If that is the case, you should checkout the `lookup_field` option. [Link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers)

You're Serializer class would look something like:

```
class GameProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    """ 
    """
    user_pk = serializers.Field(source='user.id')

    class Meta:
        model = GameProfile
        lookup_field = 'user_pk'  # Might have to use 'user__id'
```

Comment: correct, I tried to chane the lookup field on my seralizer but I got error AttributeError at /api/gamers/gameprofile/1/ 'User' object has no attribute 'user__pk'

Comment: i tried using user_pk, user_id, user__pk, user__id and also user.id and user.pk but none worked for me.. keep getting the same error

Comment: I just did some more testing the lookup_field works when the field is not foriegn key

Comment: Instead of `user_pk = serializers.Field(source='user.id')` have you tried `user = serializers.RelatedField()`?