# Dynamic URL for ViewSets in Django REST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have Group and Us Model let say and I want to filter all groups for any user.

url-> `groups/<user_id>/`

I want to create a viewset for this but I don't know how to craete dynamic url like above I mentioned. I guess viewset takes dynamic url for the model itself for curd operation like `/group/<grouop_id>/` but in my case dynamic parem is not `pk` but other field in that model.

I hope my question makes any sense , is this feasible in in viewsets, If yes then any idea what will the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Groups model looks like:

```
class Group(models.Model)
    user = models.OneToOneField('User')
```

The serializer will be:

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user_id = serializers.Field(source='user.id')

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        lookup_field = 'user_id'
```

Url will be:

```
/group/<user_id>
```

For further reference read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22303389/django-rest-framework-change-primary-key-to-use-a-unqiue-field).

Comment: User is a `FK` , So It can have more then one entry thus it is giving this error  **get() returned more than one groups**

Comment: models.OneToOneField ensure only 1 object is returned. Can you check with user__id. See if that works with you.

Comment: no it doesn't , for one entry it will work , but for more then one its not